# Using Microsoft Kinect on a PC

Tags: pc, kinect

Microsoft recently [released an SDK](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/kinectsdk/) for the Kinect for Windows development. Does that mean if I go buy a Kinect, I can use it on my PC now? I'm a developer and would like to fidget around with it, but I want to make sure it will work on my PC first because I don't have an XBOX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will work on your PC (provided it has a USB port).

There is also an open source "SDK" with reverse engineered drivers for Windows and Linux, if the licence for the official SDK is to prohibitive (there are a lot of licence restrictions on the use of the official SDK, a commercial SDK might be released later on).

Comment: Before the SDK dropped, Brekel did wonders for those of us dying to play with Kinect mocap data. http://www.brekel.com/?page_id=155